# How to apply fixture and parameterize in a csv-driver pytest example

Tags: python, pytest

**testcase.csv**

```
3,4,5,scalene,6
...
```

For each line,`line[0:3]` are the three sides of a triangle,`line[3]` is category and `line[4]` is area

Now there are two functions to be tested.

`classify(sides:list)->str`:calculate the category of a triangle

`area(sides:list)->float`:calculate the area of a triangle

**test code**

```
testcase=[]
# @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
# def setUp():
with open("test\\triangle\\testcase.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line=line.split(",")
        sides=list(map(lambda x:int(x),line[0:3]))
        expected_type=line[3]
        expected_area=float(line[4])
        testcase.append((sides,expected_type,expected_area))
    # print("setup")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("sides,expected_category,expected_area",testcase)
def test_classify(sides,expected_category,expected_area):
    assert classify.classify(sides)==expected_category

@pytest.mark.parametrize("sides,expected_category,expected_area",testcase)
def test_classify(sides,expected_category,expected_area):
    assert math.isclose(area.area(sides),expected_area,abs_tol=1e-5)
```

It works.But if I apply fixture to setup like below,it goes wrong.

```
testcase=[]
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setUp():
    with open("test\\triangle\\testcase.csv","r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line=line.split(",")
            sides=list(map(lambda x:int(x),line[0:3]))
            expected_type=line[3]
            expected_area=float(line[4])
            testcase.append((sides,expected_type,expected_area))
    print("setup")
```

So my question is how to apply both fixture and parameterize in this example,and what's the most elegant way for this instance furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a few thoughts..

1. The "most elegant way", I believe, would be to not try to import this from a csv everytime you run, but rather include it in the script itself. This may not be inside of your planned workflow, however, so:
2. If you really want to load from the csv file - I don't see a major issue with it being at the top of your script outside of a fixture *if you are careful to never edit it within a test*. I understand the preference for a fixture for test isolation, but the fixture you are choosing is already module/class scope so I don't know if that is a strong concern for you at the moment.
3. The main issue blocking you from using a fixture in this case is that pytest will run collection before it ever processes your fixture. This means that it will seek to process all parameterize calls to determine how many tests to run before starting to run any tests - so those parameterize calls (to the best of my knowledge) can't be based on information that isn't already known at collection time.
4. With that said, if your goal for this is test isolation, you can do something similar with a cached function:

```py
import pytest
import functools

@functools.cache
def process_csv():
    # Process your csv here. Build and *return* the test case list.
    # `cache` will make sure that the same value is given to every use
    # *without* regenerating it.

@pytest.mark.parametrize(..., process_csv())
def test_abc(...):
    assert ... == ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize(..., process_csv())
def test_xyz(...):
    assert ... == ...
```

Comment: But I think include testcase in the script itself means less flexible and you need to modify the script when adding new testcase.

Answer (score 0):

Tests parameters are used in tests collection time, `fixture`s are running in execution time.

To create parameters from the CSV file you can create a function and give it as the source to `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

```
__lines = []


def get_test_cases():
    global __lines
    if len(__lines) == 0:
        with open("test\\triangle\\testcase.csv","r") as f:
            __lines = f.readlines()
    for line in __lines:
        line = line.split(",")
        sides = list(map(lambda x: int(x), line[0:3]))
        expected_type = line[3]
        expected_area = float(line[4])
        yield sides, expected_type, expected_area


@pytest.mark.parametrize("sides, expected_category, expected_area", get_test_cases())
def test_classify(sides, expected_category, expected_area):
    assert classify.classify(sides) == expected_category


@pytest.mark.parametrize("sides, expected_category, expected_area", get_test_cases())
def test_area(sides, expected_category, expected_area):
    assert math.isclose(area.area(sides), expected_area,abs_tol=1e-5)
```

You also need to give different test names if they are both in the same file.